# Using the external property feature in SonarQube scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Starting from version 2.9 of the SonarQube scanner it is possible to reference variables from within `sonar-project.properties`:

https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/2017/03/2017-03-15-sonarqube-scanner-2.9-released.html

To me, the obvious use case of this feature is to avoid having to declare the version of the project twice (once in code and once in `sonar-project.properties`).

For example, in Swift projects the version is defined in a .plist file as an XML value. **Is there an obvious simple method to retrieve this value and reference it in the `sonar-project.properties` file?**

**Update:** I have managed to get this to work in a TeamCity build (command line build step):

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.APP_VERSION' value='$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" "MyApp/Info.plist")']"
```

and then referencing the variable in `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.projectVersion=${env.APP_VERSION}
```

Answer (score 2):

No '*obvious simple method*' that I can think of. One approach could be to have a small script picking the version from the .plist and setting it as an environment variable. Environment variable which can then [be referenced](https://www.sonarsource.com/resources/product-news/2017/03/2017-03-15-sonarqube-scanner-2.9-released.html) from `sonar-project.properties`.